# Problems with OpenCV compilation with static linking on pandaboard

Tags: opencv, static, pandaboard

I installed opencv with static linking on pandaboard using BUILD_SHARED_LIBS=0 option. I am using ubuntu 11.10. I also built 3rd party libraries png, jpeg, jasper and zlib. (cmake options BUILD_PNG=ON BUILD_JASPER=ON BUILD_JPEG=ON BUILD_ZLIB=ON WITH_JPEG=ON WITH_PNG=ON WITH_JASPER=ON). My opencv installation was successful. However when I compile a test program I get a number of undefined reference to errors. All of these errors seem to be related to jpeg, png and jasper libraries but i can't understand why libhighgui is not able to refer to 3rd party libraries when I explicitly link them. Here is how I compile my program :

`g++ -static face_recognition.cpp -o fcarm -I/home/nandhini/opencv/2.4.2static/include/opencv -I/home/nandhini/opencv/2.4.2static/include -L/home/nandhini/opencv/2.4.2static/lib/ -L/home/nandhini/opencv/2.4.2static/share/OpenCV/3rdparty/lib -llibjpeg -llibjasper -llibpng -lzlib -lopencv_core -lopencv_contrib -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_ml -lopencv_video -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_flann -lopencv_photo -lopencv_legacy -pthread -lm -lrt -lstdc++ -ldl`

I've been stuck with this problem for a long time now and I would really appreciate it if someone can help me solve the problem. Please help, thanks !

Here is a list of my errors :

`/home/nandhini/opencv/2.4.2static/lib//libopencv_core.a(persistence.cpp.o): In function`icvGets(CvFileStorage*, char*, int)':
persistence.cpp:(.text._ZL7icvGetsP13CvFileStoragePci+0x7e): undefined reference to `gzgets'
/home/nandhini/opencv/2.4.2static/lib//libopencv_core.a(persistence.cpp.o): In function`_ZL16icvYMLSkipSpacesP13CvFileStoragePcii.constprop.61':
persistence.cpp:(.text._ZL16icvYMLSkipSpacesP13CvFileStoragePcii.constprop.61+0x11e): undefined reference to `gzeof'
/home/nandhini/opencv/2.4.2static/lib//libopencv_core.a(persistence.cpp.o): In function`icvPuts(CvFileStorage*, char const*)':
persistence.cpp:(.text._ZL7icvPutsP13CvFileStoragePKc+0x138): undefined reference to `gzputs'
/home/nandhini/opencv/2.4.2static/lib//libopencv_core.a(persistence.cpp.o): In function`icvXMLSkipSpaces(CvFileStorage*, char*, int)':
persistence.cpp:(.text._ZL16icvXMLSkipSpacesP13CvFileStoragePci+0x1a2): undefined reference to `gzeof'
/home/nandhini/opencv/2.4.2static/lib//libopencv_core.a(persistence.cpp.o): In function`icvClose(CvFileStorage*, std::basic_string, std::allocator >*)':
persistence.cpp:(.text._ZL8icvCloseP13CvFileStoragePSs+0x132): undefined reference to `gzclose'
/home/nandhini/opencv/2.4.2static/lib//libopencv_core.a(persistence.cpp.o): In function`cvOpenFileStorage':
persistence.cpp:(.text.cvOpenFileStorage+0x1b0): undefined reference to `gzrewind'
persistence.cpp:(.text.cvOpenFileStorage+0x6b6): undefined reference to`gzclose'
persistence.cpp:(.text.cvOpenFileStorage+0x734): undefined reference to `gzopen'
persistence.cpp:(.text.cvOpenFileStorage+0xcd4): undefined reference to`gzclose'
/home/nandhini/opencv/2.4.2static/lib//libopencv_highgui.a(grfmt_jpeg2000.cpp.o): In function `cv::JasperInitializer::~JasperInitializer()':
grfmt_jpeg2000.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv17JasperInitializerD2Ev[_ZN2cv17JasperInitializerD5Ev]+0x4): undefined reference to`jas_cleanup'
/home/nandhini/opencv/2.4.2static/lib//libopencv_highgui.a(grfmt_jpeg2000.cpp.o): In function `cv::Jpeg2KDecoder::close()':
grfmt_jpeg2000.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv13Jpeg2KDecoder5closeEv+0x8): undefined reference to`jas_stream_close'
grfmt_jpeg2000.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv13Jpeg2KDecoder5closeEv+0x14): undefined reference to `jas_image_destroy'
/home/nandhini/opencv/2.4.2static/lib//libopencv_highgui.a(grfmt_jpeg2000.cpp.o): In function`cv::Jpeg2KDecoder::readHeader()':
grfmt_jpeg2000.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv13Jpeg2KDecoder10readHeaderEv+0xe): undefined reference to `jas_stream_fopen'
grfmt_jpeg2000.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv13Jpeg2KDecoder10readHeaderEv+0x1e): undefined reference to`jas_image_decode'
/home/nandhini/opencv/2.4.2static/lib//libopencv_highgui.a(grfmt_jpeg2000.cpp.o): In function `cv::Jpeg2KDecoder::readData(cv::Mat&)':
grfmt_jpeg2000.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv13Jpeg2KDecoder8readDataERNS_3MatE+0x5c): undefined reference to`jas_image_getcmptbytype'
grfmt_jpeg2000.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv13Jpeg2KDecoder8readDataERNS_3MatE+0x68): undefined reference to `jas_image_getcmptbytype'
grfmt_jpeg2000.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv13Jpeg2KDecoder8readDataERNS_3MatE+0x74): undefined reference to`jas_image_getcmptbytype'
grfmt_jpeg2000.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv13Jpeg2KDecoder8readDataERNS_3MatE+0xb8): undefined reference to `jas_image_getcmptbytype'
grfmt_jpeg2000.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv13Jpeg2KDecoder8readDataERNS_3MatE+0x126): undefined reference to`jas_matrix_create'
grfmt_jpeg2000.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv13Jpeg2KDecoder8readDataERNS_3MatE+0x13e): undefined reference to `jas_image_readcmpt'
grfmt_jpeg2000.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv13Jpeg2KDecoder8readDataERNS_3MatE+0x16e): undefined reference to`jas_matrix_destroy'
grfmt_jpeg2000.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv13Jpeg2KDecoder8readDataERNS_3MatE+0x184): undefined reference to `jas_cmprof_createfromclrspc'
grfmt_jpeg2000.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv13Jpeg2KDecoder8readDataERNS_3MatE+0x194): undefined reference to`jas_image_chclrspc'
grfmt_jpeg2000.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv13Jpeg2KDecoder8readDataERNS_3MatE+0x1a2): undefined reference to `jas_image_destroy'
grfmt_jpeg2000.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv13Jpeg2KDecoder8readDataERNS_3MatE+0x1ac): undefined reference to`jas_cmprof_destroy'
grfmt_jpeg2000.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv13Jpeg2KDecoder8readDataERNS_3MatE+0x220): undefined reference to `jas_cmprof_destroy'
/home/nandhini/opencv/2.4.2static/lib//libopencv_highgui.a(grfmt_jpeg2000.cpp.o): In function`cv::Jpeg2KEncoder::writeComponent8u(void*, cv::Mat const&)':
grfmt_jpeg2000.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv13Jpeg2KEncoder16writeComponent8uEPvRKNS_3MatE+0x1c): undefined reference to `jas_matrix_create'
grfmt_jpeg2000.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv13Jpeg2KEncoder16writeComponent8uEPvRKNS_3MatE+0x86): undefined reference to`jas_image_writecmpt'
grfmt_jpeg2000.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv13Jpeg2KEncoder16writeComponent8uEPvRKNS_3MatE+0xa0): undefined reference to `jas_matrix_destroy'
/home/nandhini/opencv/2.4.2static/lib//libopencv_highgui.a(grfmt_jpeg2000.cpp.o): In function`cv::Jpeg2KEncoder::writeComponent16u(void*, cv::Mat const&)':
grfmt_jpeg2000.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv13Jpeg2KEncoder17writeComponent16uEPvRKNS_3MatE+0x1c): undefined reference to `jas_matrix_create'
grfmt_jpeg2000.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv13Jpeg2KEncoder17writeComponent16uEPvRKNS_3MatE+0x86): undefined reference to`jas_image_writecmpt'
grfmt_jpeg2000.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv13Jpeg2KEncoder17writeComponent16uEPvRKNS_3MatE+0xa0): undefined reference to `jas_matrix_destroy'
/home/nandhini/opencv/2.4.2static/lib//libopencv_highgui.a(grfmt_jpeg2000.cpp.o): In function`cv::Jpeg2KEncoder::write(cv::Mat const&, std::vector > const&)':
grfmt_jpeg2000.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv13Jpeg2KEncoder5writeERKNS_3MatERKSt6vectorIiSaIiEE+0x5a): undefined reference to `jas_image_create'
grfmt_jpeg2000.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv13Jpeg2KEncoder5writeERKNS_3MatERKSt6vectorIiSaIiEE+0x8c): undefined reference to`jas_image_destroy'
grfmt_jpeg2000.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv13Jpeg2KEncoder5writeERKNS_3MatERKSt6vectorIiSaIiEE+0xbe): undefined reference to `jas_stream_fopen'
grfmt_jpeg2000.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv13Jpeg2KEncoder5writeERKNS_3MatERKSt6vectorIiSaIiEE+0xcc): undefined reference to`jas_image_strtofmt'
grfmt_jpeg2000.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv13Jpeg2KEncoder5writeERKNS_3MatERKSt6vectorIiSaIiEE+0xda): undefined reference to `jas_image_encode'
grfmt_jpeg2000.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv13Jpeg2KEncoder5writeERKNS_3MatERKSt6vectorIiSaIiEE+0xe8): undefined reference to`jas_stream_close'
/home/nandhini/opencv/2.4.2static/lib//libopencv_highgui.a(grfmt_jpeg2000.cpp.o): In function `_GLOBAL__sub_I_grfmt_jpeg2000.cpp':
grfmt_jpeg2000.cpp:(.text.startup._GLOBAL__sub_I_grfmt_jpeg2000.cpp+0x2): undefined reference to`jas_init'
/home/nandhini/opencv/2.4.2static/lib//libopencv_imgproc.a(templmatch.cpp.o): In function `cv::crossCorr(cv::Mat const&, cv::Mat const&, cv::Mat&, cv::Size_<int>, int, cv::Point_<int>, double, int)':
templmatch.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv9crossCorrERKNS_3MatES2_RS0_NS_5Size_IiEEiNS_6Point_IiEEdi+0x318): undefined reference to`cv::getOptimalDFTSize(int)'
templmatch.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv9crossCorrERKNS_3MatES2_RS0_NS_5Size_IiEEiNS_6Point_IiEEdi+0x33c): undefined reference to `cv::getOptimalDFTSize(int)'
templmatch.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv9crossCorrERKNS_3MatES2_RS0_NS_5Size_IiEEiNS_6Point_IiEEdi+0x7c4): undefined reference to`cv::dft(cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_OutputArray const&, int, int)'
templmatch.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv9crossCorrERKNS_3MatES2_RS0_NS_5Size_IiEEiNS_6Point_IiEEdi+0xefc): undefined reference to `cv::dft(cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_OutputArray const&, int, int)'
templmatch.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv9crossCorrERKNS_3MatES2_RS0_NS_5Size_IiEEiNS_6Point_IiEEdi+0xf66): undefined reference to`cv::mulSpectrums(cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_OutputArray const&, int, bool)'
templmatch.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv9crossCorrERKNS_3MatES2_RS0_NS_5Size_IiEEiNS_6Point_IiEEdi+0xf8e): undefined reference to `cv::dft(cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_OutputArray const&, int, int)'
/home/nandhini/opencv/2.4.2static/lib//libopencv_highgui.a(grfmt_png.cpp.o): In function`cv::PngDecoder::readDataFromBuf(void*, unsigned char*, unsigned int)':
grfmt_png.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10PngDecoder15readDataFromBufEPvPhj+0xc): undefined reference to `png_get_io_ptr'
grfmt_png.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10PngDecoder15readDataFromBufEPvPhj+0x10a): undefined reference to`png_error'
/home/nandhini/opencv/2.4.2static/lib//libopencv_highgui.a(grfmt_png.cpp.o): In function `cv::PngDecoder::close()':
grfmt_png.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10PngDecoder5closeEv+0x26): undefined reference to`png_destroy_read_struct'
/home/nandhini/opencv/2.4.2static/lib//libopencv_highgui.a(grfmt_png.cpp.o): In function `cv::PngDecoder::readHeader()':
grfmt_png.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10PngDecoder10readHeaderEv+0x18): undefined reference to`png_create_read_struct'
grfmt_png.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10PngDecoder10readHeaderEv+0x22): undefined reference to `png_create_info_struct'
grfmt_png.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10PngDecoder10readHeaderEv+0x2a): undefined reference to`png_create_info_struct'
grfmt_png.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10PngDecoder10readHeaderEv+0x6a): undefined reference to `png_set_longjmp_fn'
grfmt_png.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10PngDecoder10readHeaderEv+0xae): undefined reference to`png_init_io'
grfmt_png.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10PngDecoder10readHeaderEv+0xd8): undefined reference to `png_read_info'
grfmt_png.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10PngDecoder10readHeaderEv+0xf0): undefined reference to`png_get_IHDR'
grfmt_png.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10PngDecoder10readHeaderEv+0x166): undefined reference to `png_set_read_fn'
/home/nandhini/opencv/2.4.2static/lib//libopencv_highgui.a(grfmt_png.cpp.o): In function`cv::PngEncoder::write(cv::Mat const&, std::vector > const&)':
grfmt_png.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10PngEncoder5writeERKNS_3MatERKSt6vectorIiSaIiEE+0x18): undefined reference to `png_create_write_struct'
grfmt_png.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10PngEncoder5writeERKNS_3MatERKSt6vectorIiSaIiEE+0x7a): undefined reference to`png_create_info_struct'
grfmt_png.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10PngEncoder5writeERKNS_3MatERKSt6vectorIiSaIiEE+0x9e): undefined reference to `png_set_longjmp_fn'
grfmt_png.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10PngEncoder5writeERKNS_3MatERKSt6vectorIiSaIiEE+0xce): undefined reference to`png_set_write_fn'
grfmt_png.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10PngEncoder5writeERKNS_3MatERKSt6vectorIiSaIiEE+0x14a): undefined reference to `png_set_compression_mem_level'
grfmt_png.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10PngEncoder5writeERKNS_3MatERKSt6vectorIiSaIiEE+0x158): undefined reference to`png_set_compression_strategy'
grfmt_png.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10PngEncoder5writeERKNS_3MatERKSt6vectorIiSaIiEE+0x19a): undefined reference to `png_set_IHDR'
grfmt_png.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10PngEncoder5writeERKNS_3MatERKSt6vectorIiSaIiEE+0x1ae): undefined reference to`png_write_info'
grfmt_png.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10PngEncoder5writeERKNS_3MatERKSt6vectorIiSaIiEE+0x1ba): undefined reference to `png_set_bgr'
grfmt_png.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10PngEncoder5writeERKNS_3MatERKSt6vectorIiSaIiEE+0x1ce): undefined reference to`png_set_swap'
grfmt_png.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10PngEncoder5writeERKNS_3MatERKSt6vectorIiSaIiEE+0x208): undefined reference to `png_write_image'
grfmt_png.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10PngEncoder5writeERKNS_3MatERKSt6vectorIiSaIiEE+0x21c): undefined reference to`png_write_end'
grfmt_png.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10PngEncoder5writeERKNS_3MatERKSt6vectorIiSaIiEE+0x22e): undefined reference to `png_destroy_write_struct'
grfmt_png.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10PngEncoder5writeERKNS_3MatERKSt6vectorIiSaIiEE+0x284): undefined reference to`png_init_io'
grfmt_png.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10PngEncoder5writeERKNS_3MatERKSt6vectorIiSaIiEE+0x2c6): undefined reference to `png_set_filter'
grfmt_png.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10PngEncoder5writeERKNS_3MatERKSt6vectorIiSaIiEE+0x2d4): undefined reference to`png_set_compression_level'
/home/nandhini/opencv/2.4.2static/lib//libopencv_highgui.a(grfmt_png.cpp.o): In function `cv::PngDecoder::readData(cv::Mat&)':
grfmt_png.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10PngDecoder8readDataERNS_3MatE+0x8c): undefined reference to`png_set_longjmp_fn'
grfmt_png.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10PngDecoder8readDataERNS_3MatE+0xfa): undefined reference to `png_set_gray_to_rgb'
grfmt_png.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10PngDecoder8readDataERNS_3MatE+0x102): undefined reference to`png_read_update_info'
grfmt_png.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10PngDecoder8readDataERNS_3MatE+0x126): undefined reference to `png_read_image'
grfmt_png.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10PngDecoder8readDataERNS_3MatE+0x12e): undefined reference to`png_read_end'
grfmt_png.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10PngDecoder8readDataERNS_3MatE+0x14e): undefined reference to `png_set_palette_to_rgb'
grfmt_png.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10PngDecoder8readDataERNS_3MatE+0x16a): undefined reference to`png_set_rgb_to_gray'
grfmt_png.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10PngDecoder8readDataERNS_3MatE+0x170): undefined reference to `png_set_bgr'
grfmt_png.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10PngDecoder8readDataERNS_3MatE+0x178): undefined reference to`png_set_strip_alpha'
grfmt_png.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10PngDecoder8readDataERNS_3MatE+0x180): undefined reference to `png_set_swap'
grfmt_png.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10PngDecoder8readDataERNS_3MatE+0x18c): undefined reference to`png_set_expand_gray_1_2_4_to_8'
grfmt_png.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10PngDecoder8readDataERNS_3MatE+0x194): undefined reference to `png_set_strip_16'
/home/nandhini/opencv/2.4.2static/lib//libopencv_highgui.a(grfmt_png.cpp.o): In function`cv::PngEncoder::writeDataToBuf(void*, unsigned char*, unsigned int)':
grfmt_png.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10PngEncoder14writeDataToBufEPvPhj+0x16): undefined reference to `png_get_io_ptr'
/home/nandhini/opencv/2.4.2static/lib//libopencv_highgui.a(grfmt_jpeg.cpp.o): In function`_ZN2cvL16my_jpeg_load_dhtEP22jpeg_decompress_structPhPP9JHUFF_TBLS5_.constprop.30':
grfmt_jpeg.cpp:(.text.unlikely._ZN2cvL16my_jpeg_load_dhtEP22jpeg_decompress_structPhPP9JHUFF_TBLS5_.constprop.30+0xa4): undefined reference to `jpeg_alloc_huff_table'
/home/nandhini/opencv/2.4.2static/lib//libopencv_highgui.a(grfmt_jpeg.cpp.o): In function`cv::JpegEncoder::write(cv::Mat const&, std::vector > const&)':
grfmt_jpeg.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv11JpegEncoder5writeERKNS_3MatERKSt6vectorIiSaIiEE+0x6e): undefined reference to `jpeg_CreateCompress'
grfmt_jpeg.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv11JpegEncoder5writeERKNS_3MatERKSt6vectorIiSaIiEE+0x78): undefined reference to`jpeg_std_error'
grfmt_jpeg.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv11JpegEncoder5writeERKNS_3MatERKSt6vectorIiSaIiEE+0xdc): undefined reference to `jpeg_destroy_compress'
grfmt_jpeg.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv11JpegEncoder5writeERKNS_3MatERKSt6vectorIiSaIiEE+0x194): undefined reference to`jpeg_set_defaults'
grfmt_jpeg.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv11JpegEncoder5writeERKNS_3MatERKSt6vectorIiSaIiEE+0x1a2): undefined reference to `jpeg_set_quality'
grfmt_jpeg.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv11JpegEncoder5writeERKNS_3MatERKSt6vectorIiSaIiEE+0x1ae): undefined reference to`jpeg_start_compress'
grfmt_jpeg.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv11JpegEncoder5writeERKNS_3MatERKSt6vectorIiSaIiEE+0x1f6): undefined reference to `jpeg_write_scanlines'
grfmt_jpeg.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv11JpegEncoder5writeERKNS_3MatERKSt6vectorIiSaIiEE+0x208): undefined reference to`jpeg_finish_compress'
grfmt_jpeg.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv11JpegEncoder5writeERKNS_3MatERKSt6vectorIiSaIiEE+0x25e): undefined reference to `jpeg_stdio_dest'
grfmt_jpeg.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv11JpegEncoder5writeERKNS_3MatERKSt6vectorIiSaIiEE+0x2a6): undefined reference to`jpeg_write_scanlines'
grfmt_jpeg.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv11JpegEncoder5writeERKNS_3MatERKSt6vectorIiSaIiEE+0x2fa): undefined reference to `jpeg_write_scanlines'
/home/nandhini/opencv/2.4.2static/lib//libopencv_highgui.a(grfmt_jpeg.cpp.o): In function`cv::JpegDecoder::close()':
grfmt_jpeg.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv11JpegDecoder5closeEv+0xa): undefined reference to `jpeg_destroy_decompress'
/home/nandhini/opencv/2.4.2static/lib//libopencv_highgui.a(grfmt_jpeg.cpp.o): In function`cv::JpegDecoder::readData(cv::Mat&)':
grfmt_jpeg.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv11JpegDecoder8readDataERNS_3MatE+0x90): undefined reference to `jpeg_start_decompress'
grfmt_jpeg.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv11JpegDecoder8readDataERNS_3MatE+0x10a): undefined reference to`jpeg_read_scanlines'
grfmt_jpeg.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv11JpegDecoder8readDataERNS_3MatE+0x15a): undefined reference to `jpeg_finish_decompress'
/home/nandhini/opencv/2.4.2static/lib//libopencv_highgui.a(grfmt_jpeg.cpp.o): In function`cv::JpegDecoder::readHeader()':
grfmt_jpeg.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv11JpegDecoder10readHeaderEv+0x20): undefined reference to `jpeg_std_error'
grfmt_jpeg.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv11JpegDecoder10readHeaderEv+0x56): undefined reference to`jpeg_CreateDecompress'
grfmt_jpeg.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv11JpegDecoder10readHeaderEv+0x92): undefined reference to `jpeg_stdio_src'
grfmt_jpeg.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv11JpegDecoder10readHeaderEv+0x9a): undefined reference to`jpeg_read_header'
grfmt_jpeg.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv11JpegDecoder10readHeaderEv+0x13c): undefined reference to `jpeg_resync_to_restart'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The **order** in which libraries are linked **matters**! This [might be](https://web.archive.org/web/20170831212324/http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/gccintro/gccintro_18.html) the [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45141/176769).

Comment: Thanks, that worked ! I looked at pkg_config/opencv.pc and looked at the order in which libraries are linked. That worked ! thanks a lot !!